Strategy pattern to filter objects, how to compose them?
Say I have come class that looks like this
class Product {
    double Price;
    String name;
    String category;
}

I have a client facing API that allows users to filter my list of objects based on the name or rating or price. These are implemented through Strategy Pattern like this
interface IFilterStrategy {
    boolean apply(Product product);
}

class NameMatchStrategy implements IFilterStrategy {
    String name;
    public NameMatchStrategy(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    boolean apply(Product product) {
        return product.getName().equals(name);
    }
}

class PriceMatchStrategy implements IFilterStrategy {
    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    public StringMatchStrategy(double minVal, double maxVal) {
        this.minVal = minVal;
        this.maxVal = maxVal;
    }

    boolean apply(Product product) {
        return product.getPrice() >= minVal && product.getPrice() <= maxVal;
    }
}

My question is what if I wanted to add a new Strategy, say that matches just the Prefix of a name. So perhaps a user passes "iph" and I should be able to find a product name that's called "iphone" and match it with that. I know I can create another NamePrefixMatchStrategy, but what if in the future I want to extend this Prefix strategy to say, Category as well. Like a user could pass in "ph" and I should find the category "phone".
The brute force solution would be to just create a CategoryPrefixMatchStrategy, but the number of my strategies would quickly become hard to maintain.
What's the best design pattern to get around this? Should I create a generic StringMatchStrategy or something, I'm just not sure how to incorporate this into my current design.

You could create interfaces with default methods. So you can reuse the code, but you still have the problem with the number of strategies.
abstract class ExactMatchStrategy implements IFilterStrategy {

    String value;

    public ExactMatchStrategy(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean apply(Product product) {
        return getFieldValue(product).equals(value);
    }

    public abstract String getFieldValue(Product product);

}

class ExactNameMatchStrategy extends ExactMatchStrategy {
    
    public ExactNameMatchStrategy(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public String getFieldValue(Product product) {
         return product.getName();
    }
}

class ExactCategoryMatchStrategy extends ExactMatchStrategy {
    
    public ExactCategoryMatchStrategy(String category) {
        super(category);
    }

    public String getFieldValue(Product product) {
         return product.getCategory();
    }
}

Or with the new Java function package as follows:
class ExactMatchStrategy implements IFilterStrategy {

    String value;
    Function<Product, String> getField;

    public ExactMatchStrategy(String value, Function<Product, String> getField) {
        this.value = value;
        this.getField = getField;
    }

    public boolean apply(Product product) {
        return getField.apply(product).equals(value);
    }

}

class ExactNameMatchStrategy extends ExactMatchStrategy {
    public ExactNameMatchStrategy(String name) {
        super(name, (p) -> p.getName());
    }
}

class ExactCategoryMatchStrategy extends ExactMatchStrategy {

    public ExactCategoryMatchStrategy(String category) {
        super(category, (p) -> p.getCategory());
    }
}

Then you could also instantiate inline
ExactMatchStrategy exactNameMatcher = new ExactMatchStrategy(name, (p) -> p.getName());
ExactMatchStrategy exactCategoryMatcher = new ExactMatchStrategy(category, (p) -> p.getCategory());


It's a matter of opinion, but those strategies aren't really extensive, so you might as well just create them in factory methods,
class NameMatchingStrategies {
 public static IFilterStrategy exactMatch(String toMatch) {
  return product -> product.getName().equals(toMatch);
 }
 public static IFilterStrategy containsMatch(String toContain) {
  return product -> product.getName().contains(toContain);
 }
}

You can make that generic with
 public static IFilterStrategy operatorMatch(String toMatch, BiPredicate<String> operator) {
   return product -> operator.test(product.getName(), toMatch);
 }

but it really seems overengineered to do this for the exact match for example (return operatorMatch(name, String::equals)), and even for a prefix match (return operatorMatch(prefix, String::startsWith)).
You can of course make this a proper class
class ProductNameMatchingStrategy {
 private final BiPredicate<String> matcher;
 private final String toMatch;

 public boolean apply(Product product) {
  return matcher.test(product.getName(), toMatch);
 }
}

but that's just more code. Again, a matter of taste.
To check other fields, you can use the same pattern
 public static IFilterStrategy extractingOperatorMatch(String toMatch,
                  Function<Product, String> extractor,
                  BiPredicate<String> matcher) {
  return product -> matcher.test(extractor.apply(product), toMatch);
 }

This is an example of composition over inheritance. You can then easily create any combination of the two (retrieval from product and matcher method). A category matcher would then be eg extractingMatch("cat", Product::getCategory, String::contains) ("products that contain 'cat' in its category field").
You can and probably should by also making this null-safe in case the field is not set, but that's beyond the scope of this question, and you'd have to decide how to handle the null case (always matches? never matches? evaluate other matcher?).
Oh, and you can of course generify it to also supply a framework for the other strategies,
public static <T> IFilterStrategy extractingMatcher(T toMatch,
                  Function<Product, T> extractor,
                  BiPredicate<T> matcher) {
  return product -> matcher.test(extractor.apply(product), toMatch);
}

with a usage like
public static IFilterStrategy minPriceFilter(Integer min) {
 return product -> extractingMatch(min,
                   Product::getPrice,
                   p -> p >= min);
 }

public static IFilterStrategy maxPriceFilter(Integer max) {
 return product -> extractingMatch(max,
                   Product::getPrice,
                   p -> p <= max);
 }

And since you can construct combined filters like this
public static IFilterStrategy and(IFilterStrategy s1,
                                  IFilterStrategy s2) {
 return p -> s1.apply(p) && s2.apply(p);
}

you can create your minMaxFilter with
IFilterStrategy minMaxPrice = and(minPriceFilter(min),
                                  maxPriceFilter(max));

But your IFilterStrategy is just a Predicate<Product> anyway, so you might as well use that (it already contains the and() and or() composition methods); you can construct them in exactly the way described above.

First, to give clients more flexibility, I would use Predicate<Product> instead of creating IFilterStrategy.
Second, it seems like there are 2 parts to your problem - which field to test, and how to test it. You could have something like a FieldExtractingPredicate which provides an interface to compose a predicate of the 2 parts:
public class FieldExtractingPredicate<T> implements Predicate<Product> {

    private final Function<Product, T> fieldExtractingFunction;
    private final Predicate<T> fieldPredicate;

    public FieldExtractingPredicate(Function<Product, T> fieldExtractingFunction, Predicate<T> fieldPredicate) {
        this.fieldExtractingFunction = fieldExtractingFunction;
        this.fieldPredicate = fieldPredicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Product product) {
        return fieldPredicate.test(fieldExtractingFunction.apply(product));
    }

    public static <T> Predicate<Product> fieldEqualsPredicate(Function<Product, T> fieldExtractingFunction, T matchValue) {
        return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(fieldExtractingFunction, value -> value.equals(matchValue));
    }

    public static Predicate<Product> fieldBetween(Function<Product, Double> fieldExtractingFunction, double minVal, double maxVal) {
        return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(fieldExtractingFunction, value -> value >= minVal && value <= maxVal);
    }

    public static Predicate<Product> fieldContainsPredicate(Function<Product, String> fieldExtractingFunction, String substring) {
        return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(fieldExtractingFunction, value -> value.contains(substring));
    }

    public static Predicate<Product> fieldStartsWithPredicate(Function<Product, String> fieldExtractingFunction, String prefix) {
        return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(fieldExtractingFunction, value -> value.startsWith(prefix));
    }
}

Now, adding new strategies, say "ends with" is quite simple:
    public static Predicate<Product> fieldEndsWithPredicate(Function<Product, String> fieldExtractingFunction, String suffix) {
        return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(fieldExtractingFunction, value -> value.endsWith(suffix));
    }

If you want to hide the fieldExtractingFunction from the user, you can provide factory methods for specific fields:
public static Predicate<Product> nameEquals(String expectedName) {
    return fieldEqualsPredicate(Product::getName, expectedName);
}

public static Predicate<Product> priceBetween(double minPrice, double maxPrice) {
    return fieldBetween(Product::getPrice, minPrice, maxPrice);
}

Using Predicate also allows you to compose more complicated strategies reasonably easy by using Predicate.and(), Predicate.or() and Predicate.not(). For example:
    nameEquals("basketball").and(priceBetween(10.0, 20.0));

Alternatively, you might want to leave the test function completely up to the client, and provide field-specific factory methods:
public static Predicate<Product> nameMatches(Predicate<String> nameTest) {
    return new FieldExtractingPredicate<>(Product::getName, nameTest);
}


If u wanna implement flexible strategies.
I think u can use reflect and dynamic script libs. u can google some informations about java scriptEngine in order to achieve your thoughts.
You can use reflect to get the fields in the Product class. And then write the correct script statements and execute it with scriptEngine.
